# A Name That Everyone Knows

Tags: riddle, knowledge

> My children are tall;
>   My grandchildren are shorter, but sit above everyone else;
>   My name is a joke--the kind that immature children make;
>   Some hail me by another tag, but my first is more famous.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You must be

> [Uranus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uranus_(mythology)).

`My children are tall;`

> Uranus was the father of the [Titans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Titan_(mythology)).

`My grandchildren are shorter, but sit above everyone else;`

> The Greek gods ([quite a few of them, at least](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Family_tree_of_the_Greek_gods)) are children of Titans, and they sit on Mount Olympus, above anyone else. (Thanks, Evargalo!)

The immature joke smells too bad to add here, but(t) what comes to the other name,

> the Romans took all the old Greek gods and incorporated them in their pantheon with silly names like "Jupiter" and "Mars", so Uranus probably had a Roman name too. Caelus, says Google.

Comment: This must be the correct answer. We may add that rot13(Uvf tenaqpuvyqera fvg nobir rirelbar ryfr ba Zbhag Bylzchf.)

Comment: Regarding the other name, it's strange for me, because I've always known that rot13(rira sbe Ebzna zvgubybtl uvf anzr jnf Henahf). Also this [italian wikipedia page](https://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corrispondenza_tra_divinit%C3%A0_greche_e_romane) shows it. But I could not find any reference to it; the only ones I was able to find were either rot13(Pvpreb pnyyvat uva "Pnryhf", be grkgf jvgubhg nhgube, juvpu V fhccbfr ner dhvgr zbqrea)

Answer (score 6):

A possible answer is

> [Grandgousier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grandgousier)

His child is

> [Gargantua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gargantua_and_Pantagruel), the tallest giant in François [Rabelais](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fran%C3%A7ois_Rabelais)' litterature.

And his grandchild is

> Pantagruel, another giant, but less tall than Gargantua.

His name is a joke

> Grandgousier means "big throat". That's the kind of funny-sounding names children (and Rabelais!) like to invent.

Some hail me by another tag, but my first is more famous.

> Grandgousier is also the common name given to a family of big-mouthed fishes, the [Saccopharyngiforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saccopharyngiforms), but the litterary tag is more famous than the scientific one!

Caveat:

> AFAIK, Grandgousier had only one child, and only one grandchild, while the riddle talks about children and grandchildren.